# Subtract 1 from a various range of cells and i also add 1 to another range

Tags: excel, vba

i have an excel doc that most columns need 1 subtracted every month and the left over cells to add 1.  the tricky part is returning the new value to the same cell (not using the traditional =a1-b1 formula). I am ok with this being done via a macro and running it manually on a monthly basis.  I am not familiar with VBA coding, but would like to learn how to code this.  thanks!

i am not proficient in coding a macro.  i have watched videos and read books, but i haven't found a solution yet.  i need this to happen faster than reading a 500 page book on macros or watching 100 videos on youtube.  thanks again..

Comment: Please post the doc, and show what it should look like both before and after the monthly change. That will make it easier to visualize what you're trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

I'm unwilling to write your code for you, but I would point out that if you

- copy your worksheet to a new workbook, and
- modify the columns in this copy so their cells are formulas referring to the original worksheet (± 1 as appropriate),

then you could manually copy those columns from the new workbook and paste-as-values into the original. Save this new workbook and you can re-use it the next month, too. (Or you could use different sheets within the same workbook but if you save a formulaic version as a new, separate workbook then anyone looking at the original workbook won't see any confusing "extra stuff" in it.)

Once you have that right, that might be good enough since you only do it once a month with no need for code at all! Writing code to loop through each cell in specific columns and add/subtract 1 can be done in many ways, but maybe a way to make the manual process faster and more foolproof is good enough!

But if you wished, you could use what you have as a proof of concept and proceed to

1. record that copy & paste-as-values operation as a macro,
2. Adjust the macro code to use absolute addresses instead of `ActiveWorksheet`

And then you can just open that new workbook every month and click a button.

**Or**, you could record a macro for the whole thing *(copy entire original, change columns to a formula of 'value from original sheet ± 1', copy & paste-as-values back into the original, then delete the working copy because you want to start fresh every time anyway)*... but if you're going to do that then it's probably worth writing code that implements the approach you mentioned in your question by actually incrementing the values directly instead of this 'templating then paste-as-values approach.